# Пустое пространство на сайте между блоками

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Начал писать сайт

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#alive{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}

#mid{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#rhyme{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ccc.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="alive"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="rhyme"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Но между блоками остается небольшое пустое пространство, не могу понять откуда оно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это переносы строк между div'ами, которые написаны у вас в коде

Comment: Разве перенос не тегом br делается?

Comment: Это не тот перенос. У вас в коде переносы, которые вы сделали Enter'ом - вот они и отображаются

Answer (score 5):

Вы зачем-то задаёте блокам инлайновое поведение, и у них появляются "межбуквенные" интервалы (как у любых строковых элементов).

Есть разные варианты решения данной проблемы. Например, просто закомментить эти отступы:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#alive{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}

#mid{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#rhyme{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="alive"></div><!--
--><div id="mid"></div><!--
--><div id="rhyme"></div>
```

Но лучше использовать flex или float, если Вам надо выстроить блоки в ряд. Задавать им inline-block - не очень хорошее решение.

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один прикольный способ избавиться от пробелов — сделать их нулевого размера с помощью `font-size: 0px` у контейнера. Правда, в последствии надо не забыть вернуть потомкам размер шрифта по умолчанию.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.line {
    font-size: 0;
}
.line > * {
    font-size: initial;
}

#alive {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}

#mid {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#rhyme {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ccc.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="line">
    <div id="alive"></div>
    <div id="mid"></div>
    <div id="rhyme"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать **flex-box** как сказал [Qlasandr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/281735/qlasandr)

Гайд по flexbox - [ссылка](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Данный вопрос решается в пару строк:

```css
.parent{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 1000px;
}

#alive{
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}

#mid{
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

#rhyme{
  width: 25%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div id="alive"></div>
  <div id="mid"></div>
  <div id="rhyme"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Обычный хак все знают - ставишь комментарии между блоками

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#alive{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}

#mid{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: red;
}

#rhyme{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 128, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ccc.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
     <div id="alive"></div><!-- 
     --><div id="mid"></div><!-- 
     --><div id="rhyme"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А зачем брать мой ответ и выдавать за свой? В чём прикол?

Comment: А зачем подстрекаешь меня?

Comment: В смысле - "подстрекаешь"?

Comment: @LyubaIvanova, у вас действительно очень похожий ответ, данный на час позже другого. Можете прояснить ситуацию? По сути это, вроде, не запрещено, но и не является поощряемым, особенно другими участниками)